# Spring Boot JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, http, post, junit

Does spring boot MockMVC supports HTTP POST with path parameters(@PathVariable) which the value sent from JUnit Test Case? If so, please give an example on how to do it.

Question Example: `mvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/employees/{some variable}")`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass @PathVariable using this scheme.

```
@Test
public void givenGreetURIWithPathVariable_whenMockMVC_thenResponseOK() {
    this.mockMvc
      .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/greetWithPathVariable/{name}", "John"))
      .andDo(print());

    this.mockMvc
      .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/greetWithPathVariable/{name}", "John"))
      .andDo(print());
}
```

More explanations are available here: [Integration Testing in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-in-spring)

Comment: I am looking for, if the @PathVariable works for POST